# I want access for custom field on Opportunity object

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning, soql

i create headless quick action. My action attach pdf with name 'Test Attachment for PDF'. I want name pdf file from Invoice_number__c - its a custom field (auto_number) on opportunity object. how i can do this?

Comment: Hello Bogdan. Do you use aura component or LWC? Also I would suggest to pass the recordId to the controller method

Comment: Hello Alin, thank you for your reply. I create visual force page with custom controller. I use Lightning Web Component in headless quick action. Can u say me how i can do it in recordId? I add headless quick action for my quastion

Comment: Honestly it's hard to really find an answer, even when seeing your full code. I can see you have a variable declared as public Opportunity opportunity {get; set;}. Theoretically that should be what you use to display data on the front-end. Also in your VF page button that triggers the action you should pass the opportunity.Id as a parameter so that you have access to it in the savePDF() method. And also I don't understand why you didn't used the Visualforce renderAs="pdf" functionality and you have to mix it with LWC.

Comment: @AlinParaschiv thanks, I used headless quick action (LWC) because I need to generate a pdf file and bind it to an object. If I do just RenderPdf, even though I have it written in code, but if I remove the LWC, I can only view my VisualForce page without linking the pdf document to the Opportunity object.

Comment: you can do it with VF as well, but fine, can you also add the code for your VF page?

Comment: Well, I don't see any real connection between the VF and the LWC. Describe me the flow of the functionality. You go on the Opportunity record page and do what?

Comment: I see you have added an @api recordId in your lwc. What is the output when you add console.log(this.recordId); before your savePDF function?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
Edit your generateInvoice.js-meta.xml to include the following target:

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<targets>
```

Save and deploy to SF.

Create a new Lightning Page in Lightning App Builder and copy the api(you will need it later). I'm guessing it's going to be generate_Invoice

Create a new detail page button with the following url

```
/lightning/n/generate_Invoice?c__oppId={!Opportunity.Id}
```

Note: you have to add the c__ prefix to the parameter of oppId in order to be able to pass it. Also generate_Invoice is the api from the Lightning page.

In your lwc add the following pieces of code in order to retrieve the oppId:

Import the page reference

```
import { CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
```

Remove @api from recordId

```
recordId;//remove @api decorator
```

Add the following wire function that retrieves the oppId parameter from your URL

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
   if (currentPageReference) {
      this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.c__oppId;
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, no need to add the prefix there. I wanted to emphasize that you need to add it in the button url and here:
`this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.c__oppId;`

Comment: it's fine under the recordId variable. What that error says is that you have not imported the wire decorator. Just add wire in your first import on the page
`import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';`

Comment: ah yes. My bad, I forgot to mention one part. I will edit the original response to include that too

Comment: @Bogdan any luck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133806/discussion-between-bogdan-and-alin-paraschiv).